# Declaring a duplicate variable within a loop in Java

Tags: java, eclipse, variables, selenium

I want to be able to declare a selenium driver within a loop dependant on a user choice. I want the driver to be called driver regardless of which kind it is, so that I can then use it for everything instead of having one separate set of code for IE and for Firefox. I hope that made sense, I am very new to Java.

```
 switch (browserId){
    case 1: 
            FirefoxDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

    case 2:

        InternetExplorerDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();

    default: 
            System.out.println("An error has occurred, the program will now close.");
        System.exit(0);
    }
```

This creates a compile error as I have two variables called driver, however I should never have them both existing at the same time. Is there a way around this?

Comment: `switch` declares the scope, not `case`.. Your variables are not very useful at this moment.

Comment: NEED break; statement in each case. default case don;t need break;

Comment: you could add a scope to each case `case 1: { /* code */ break; }` but that's probably not what you want because `driver` would go out of scope. The last case will need no break - that doesn't need to be the default case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want the driver to be called driver regardless of which kind it is,
>   so that I can then use it for everything instead of having one
>   separate set of code for IE and for Firefox.

If both of those classes implement a `Driver` interface (or is it `WebDriver`?), then you can simply do

```
Driver driver = null;
switch (browserId){
case 1: 
    driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    break;
case 2:
    driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
    break;
default: 
    System.out.println("An error has occurred, the program will now close.");
    System.exit(0);
}
```

Now you can use `driver`, but check for `null`.

The reason you can't do this is that a `switch` block begins a scope. If you declare a variable with name `driver`, you can't redeclare another variable with the same name in that same scope.

Comment: Too fast.  You beat me to it.

Answer (score 1):

You could do it like this:

```
WebDriver driver;                     // <-- move outside the switch
switch (browserId){
    case 1:
        driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        break;                        // <-- add breaks
    case 2:
        driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
        break;
    default:
        // exceptions are more welcome than System.exit();
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("wrong browserId: " + browserId);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If they all derive from a common type, declare the variable outside the switch.

```
Driver d = null;

switch(browserId){
     case 1: 
         d = new FireFoxDriver();
         break; // don't forget!!
     case 2: 
         d = new InternetExplorerDriver();
         break;
     ... // omitting other cases and default

}
```

If not, then you need to use different names in each case statement.